# Chrome, Windows 8, touchevents triggering mouse events

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, touch

I have a little problem.

I'm binding mouse and touch events and if it's a touch event catching the mouse event and discarding them.

I ran into a situation where something was not working right so I put in this code for testing:

```
this.timeLeft.on("click mousedown mouseup touchend touchstart", function(e){
    console.log("##########", e.type);
});
```

In this particular situation (perhaps always and I didn't notice), if I tap on timesLeft, the `touchend` event fires before the `mousedown` event does so there is no way to catch this as on `touchend`, I stop checking for mouse events.

Firstly, I want to make sure that mouse events do in fact get triggered per windows 8 or chrome when a touch event happens. I wanted to make sure that I just don't have some delegator in my code base that I am not aware of.

Secondly, what gives? This is a terrible implementation of event processing order. Is this the standard processing order for what I assume is a considered a "tap"

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 32.0.1678.0 dev-m Aura addresses this issue. Sorry.